# Cannot print in local printer using PrinterUtility

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am following a youtube post that uses this code

```
Dim printRes As Integer = 0
Dim obj As EscPosEpsonCommands.EscPosEpson = New EscPosEpsonCommands.EscPosEpson()
Dim byteValue() As Byte = New Byte() {}
byteValue = PrintExtensions.AddBytes(byteValue, obj.QrCode.Print("12345", PrinterUtility.Enums.QrCodeSize.Medio))
Dim printerPath = My.Settings.PrinterPath
PrinterUtility.PrintExtensions.Print(byteValue, printerPath)
```

I set my PrinterPath as so

```
Name: PrinterPath
Type: String
User: User
Value: \\FILINBSB-L01\\EPSON TM-T82II Receipt5
```

[image]

It gives me an error of `The Network Name Cannot Be Found`

Comment: 1st off anything with \\ is not a local printer.  It is a network share.  2nd Is this printer actually installed on \\DeviceName or \\FIKENBSB-L01? And is it actually called Epson TM-T82II Receipt5 or EPSON TM-T82II Receipt.  Also guessing the example you followed was c# because it looks like you're trying to escape the printer path which I don't think is needed in vb.net.  Try \\DeviceName\EPSON TM-T82II Receipt with a single slash after Device name

Comment: @Hursey, please see my edit. Yes it is installed in this FILINBSB-L01. Thank you for pointing out that when there are slashes it is a network share. On that note, I will remove the slashes then and see if it works.